# How to make Android multiline EditText background draw when there is no text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have programmatically defined a multiline EditText.  I set the background color, but the area it covers is invisible until I tap on its location.  Then the background color shows up, the cursor appears and editing begins as normal.

If I set a single character, say a "." in it, the background draws and so does the character.

How do I make an empty multiline EditText background draw when there is no text in it?

```
et = new EditText(mActivity.getApplication());
et.setMaxLines(20);
et.setMinLines(6);
et.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
et.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
et.setX(0.0f);
et.setY(0.0f);
et.setMinWidth(640);
et.setMinHeight(90);
et.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
et.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
et.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // todo: have good taste
```